# Grouping fields in MS Access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to group fields in MS Access form? I am using vba to move various fields in my form based on criteria. Is there a way to put some fields inside a box of some kind and move that box instead of moving the controls one at a time?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could set the Tag property of these to easily identify them, but that's about it.

Comment: Yeah, Tag or use a common prefix for their name. `If ctl.Name Like "foobar*" Then`. In some situations, a subform might be possible, but that's probably too invasive.

Comment: This would be helpful if I just wanted to hide and unhide a bunch of controls. I am trying to move them. When I only had 5-10 , I was converting the inches to twips for each controls and doing something like this:

`Me.lblTest.Move Left:=180, Top:=3359.95`

Comment: But if I could use something like a group box then I would just have to set the positions of bunch of group boxes which would be much easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the controls to move in a collection (e.g. by using the`.Tag`or`.Name`property), just loop through that collection (your group) and move every control by the same value.

In a standard module:

```vb
Public Sub MoveGroup(ByVal MovingGroup As Collection, _
                     ByVal AddLeft As Long, _
                     ByVal AddTop As Long)

    Dim CtlToMove As Control
    For Each CtlToMove In MovingGroup
        CtlToMove.Move CtlToMove.Left + AddLeft, CtlToMove.Top + AddTop
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub MoveByTagAsolute(ByRef CtlAbsolute As Control, _
                            ByVal MovingGroupTag As String, _
                            ByVal NewLeft As Long, _
                            ByVal NewTop As Long)

    Dim CtlGroup As Collection
    Set CtlGroup = New Collection
    Dim CtlToMove As Control
    For Each CtlToMove In CtlAbsolute.Parent.Controls
        If CtlToMove.Tag Like MovingGroupTag Then
            CtlGroup.Add CtlToMove
        End If
    Next
    MoveGroup CtlGroup, NewLeft - CtlAbsolute.Left, NewTop - CtlAbsolute.Top
End Sub

Public Sub MoveByTagRelative(ByRef Frm As Form, _
                             ByVal MovingGroupTag As String, _
                             ByVal AddLeft As Long, _
                             ByVal AddTop As Long)

    Dim CtlGroup As Collection
    Set CtlGroup = New Collection
    Dim CtlToMove As Control
    For Each CtlToMove In Frm.Controls
        If CtlToMove.Tag Like MovingGroupTag Then
            CtlGroup.Add CtlToMove
        End If
    Next
    MoveGroup CtlGroup, AddLeft, AddTop
End Sub
```

In the forms module:

```vb
Private Sub CommandMoveByTagAsolute_Click()
    MoveByTagAsolute Me.Controls("ControlAbsolutePos"), "move*", 2000, 3000
End Sub

Private Sub CommandMoveByTagRelative_Click()
    MoveByTagRelative Me, "*", 1000, 2000
End Sub
```

Button`CommandMoveByTagAsolute`click-event moves`ControlAbsolutePos`to the new coordinates and the rest of the group moves relative to it.

Button`CommandMoveByTagRelative`click-event moves the whole group ("*" selects all controls on form) relative.